# div style / format being lost when using show / hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using a show / hide code below. i works fine buy text format is being lost. is there anyway to prevent this? I have some markup style and style sheet coding

```
    <div id="fillit"></div>

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="para">Sci Lit 1</a>
    <div class="details">text for sci lit 1</div> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="para">Sci Lit 2</a>
    <div class="details">text for sci lit 2</div>    
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="para">Sci Lit 3</a>
    <div class="details">text for sci lit 3</div>   

<style>
.inner-boxes .box3, .details1 {display:none;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".para").click(function(){
        $("#fillit").text($(this).next(".details1").text()); 
    });
    $(".details1:first").clone().appendTo("#fillit").show();    
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

use .html() instead of .text()

change:

```
$("#fillit").text($(this).next(".details1").text());
```

to:

```
$("#fillit").html($(this).next(".details1").html());
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanmarc/ZLWQK/)

Comment: thank you so much. I spent over an hour trying to figure out what was going on. thought it was a css conflict

Answer (score 0):

in your script you have:

```
$(".para").click(function(){
    $("#fillit").text($(this).next(".details1").text()); 
});
```

Change to:

```
$(".para").click(function(){
    $("#fillit")
        .children(".details1")
        .replaceWith(
            $(this).next(".details1").clone().show()
        ); 
});
```

`.text()` only gets the inner text of the element

**NOTE:** As it has been noted in the comments, this is not the only way and might not even be the quickest. (I haven't done any tests on it myself) But it seems to me that it is all about style.
The Pros of my answer is that the solution could work in a large number of different scenarios.

Comment: You don't need to do a clone or replaceWith here, the end result is just taking come html from one div and duplicating it in display area. A simple .html() will do just that.

Comment: @ryanmarc yes but this solution also caters for other elements inside the `#fillit` and therefore is more robust. Its still a valid answer. The difference is just in the style of coding. I personally have issue with `.html()` http://api.jquery.com/html/ `Some browsers may not return HTML that exactly replicates the HTML source in an original document.`

Comment: #fillit starts as an empty div, the .children (".details1") will not match to anything so this isnt really a valid answer.

Comment: @ryanmarc yes it is because his second line is `$(".details1:first").clone().appendTo("#fillit").show();`